# Solving large-dimensional quadratic equation in integer domain

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm looking for efficient methods to solve an equation of the form

$$x^{T}Ax + x^{T}b = 0$$

for the unknown vector $x \in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times 1}$. $A \in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric, known, and singular. $b\in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times 1}$ is also known.

Of course an obvious solution would be to factor it as $x^{T}(Ax + b)$ which gives solutions $x = 0$ and $x = -A^{-1}b$. Since $A$ is singular, I would need to use the pseudo-inverse $x = -A^{+}b$, and for real-valued matrices, this gives a valid solution. BUT since I'm working with integer-valued matrices and vectors, the pseudo-inverse gives a floating point solution (currently I'm using `scipy.linalg.pinvh`) and it doesn't solve my problem.

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to solve this efficiently or can recommend a tool. Does there exist an "integer-only" pseudo-inverse? The scale of the problem is quite large ($n > 100000$), so I am afraid that optimization and MILP might be useless with a problem of this size.

**EDIT**: To clarify some things based on the comments, I am looking for *any* non-trivial solution. Ideally, also *all* non-trivial solutions, so $x = -A^{-1}b$ does not represent the full solution space.

$A$ is indeed sparse although I don't know how to extract special patterns occurring in $A$. Here is a visualization of a sample of $A$ for a specific problem instance (there are many), showing the the upper-left section. There seems to be a repeating pattern near the diagonal but it's not guaranteed to be this same pattern for other $A$s. If someone thinks I can take advantage of patterns like this to solve it, I'm all ears.

[image]

Comment: $x^T (A x + b) = 0$ does **not** imply $x=0$ or $Ax + b = 0$. It just says $Ax+b$ is orthogonal to $x$.

Comment: Of course if you're just looking for one solution, $x=0$ will do.

Comment: And if $\ker A$ is more than one-dimensional, it will contain vectors orthogonal to $b$.  Gaussian elimination will produce such a vector with rational entries, which you can then scale to get one with integer entries.

Comment: I'm looking for other solutions than the trivial solution $x = 0$. I understand your point that $(Ax + b)$ is orthogonal to $x$, but at the same time, I am still correct that solving $Ax +b = 0$ would give a solution, right? Since then, $x \cdot 0 = 0$

Comment: @TrevorPhillips Yes you are correct. However, "solving" an equation usually means finding all solutions to that equation. If this is not what you're trying to do, then you should make this clear in your question.

Comment: Isn't this a known hard problem? I'm pretty certain this is NP-complete. Also, what's the structure of your $A$? Given the size of your $n$ I'm presuming that $A$ is either sparse or has some repetitive structure (e.g. being circulant); the specific structure could have quite a lot of impact on what methods are good.

Comment: $A$ is sparse but I'm not sure about repetitive structures. I posted a screenshot of a heatmap of $A$ (only the upper-left section)

Comment: Is this problem even guaranteed to have a nontrivial solution?

Comment: In general, no. In my case, yes. Reason: I have perfect knowledge of the problem, so I already know a valid $x$ for each $A$, $b$. In practice I won't know $x$ which is why the problem is relevant